# Merging Data with Varying Column Lengths in Pandas / Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 different CSV files.  Both files have headers.  Most of the columns are the same.  Sometimes, they vary.

```
    File1.csv
    Name    Username    Alias1 
    Tom     Tomfoolery   TJZ
    Meryl   MsMeryl      Mer
    Timmy   Midsize      Yoda

    File2.csv
    Name    Username   Alias 1   Alias 2
    Bob     Firedbob   Fire      Gingy
    Tom     Tomfoolery  TJZ      Awww

   DesiredFile.csv
    Name    Username    Alias1   Alias 2
    Tom     Tomfoolery   TJZ     NA (or blank)
    Meryl   MsMeryl      Mer     NA (or blank)
    Timmy   Midsize      Yoda    NA (or blank)
    Bob     Firedbob     Fire    Gingy
    Tom     Tomfoolery   TJZ     Awww
```

So basically, I want to combine two files. I want ALL ROWS to stay in tact. I do not EVER want to combine merge rows.  This is important, because sometimes there is repeat data that I need to keep.

I want to combine the 2 files, but the headers/columns vary.

If a column exists in BOTH files, I want the data from that row to fall under that column (EX here: Name)

If a column exists in ONE file, I want everything from that column in that file to stay, but the other "rows" that didn't have that column in their file to be either NA, N/A, blank, something of the sort.

Is this possible to do easily with pandas?  I've tried a few different ways but haven't quite hit anything magical yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html). It concatenates the DataFrames and automatically fills in missing values with NaN:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
try:
    # for Python2
    from cStringIO import StringIO 
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    from io import StringIO


df1 = pd.read_table(StringIO('''
    Name    Username    Alias1 
    Tom     Tomfoolery   TJZ
    Meryl   MsMeryl      Mer
    Timmy   Midsize      Yoda'''), sep='\s+')

df2 = pd.read_table(StringIO('''
    Name    Username   Alias1   Alias2
    Bob     Firedbob   Fire      Gingy
    Tom     Tomfoolery  TJZ      Awww'''), sep='\s{2,}')

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
print(result)
```

yields

```
  Alias1 Alias2   Name    Username
0    TJZ    NaN    Tom  Tomfoolery
1    Mer    NaN  Meryl     MsMeryl
2   Yoda    NaN  Timmy     Midsize
0   Fire  Gingy    Bob    Firedbob
1    TJZ   Awww    Tom  Tomfoolery
```

---

Note that the column names are obviously sensitive to spaces -- `Alias1` is different than `Alias 1`. So to get the desired result I had to modify your File2.csv data to remove the space in `Alias 1`.

Comment: Mistakers were made.  You had an awesome fast solution. 
Going to go play with my real data now! Thanks!